# Only the circles of the last plot are drawn

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, react-hooks

I am making a component that allows the display of multiple plots in the same canvas.

everything works perfectly when a single graph is displayed.

On the real code I can also delete the circles when not needed using foo.

In my code I can also get rid of the circles with the clean-uf useEffect hook.

```
return () => {
    svg.selectAll('circle').remove();
}
```

Unfortunately, when I try to draw more plots, I fail. This problem occurs because each subsequent plot uses the circles from the previous plot. At the moment I couldn't find anything that would allow me to view all the plots together.

A well-written code should allow you to draw three dot plots together on the canvas. Then you should see red, green and blue dot plots together.

```js
const useState = React.useState;
const useRef = React.useRef;
const useEffect = React.useEffect;
const select = d3.select;
const scaleLinear = d3.scaleLinear;
const axisBottom = d3.axisBottom;
const axisLeft = d3.axisLeft;

const DotsPlot = () => {

  const [xAxisData] = useState({
    min: 100,
    max: 700
  });

  const [yAxisData] = useState({
    min: 200,
    max: 500
  });

  const [meta] = useState({
    xWidth: 600,
    yWidth: 300,
  });

  const [plots] = useState([
    [{
      x: '120',
      y: '210',
      r: '4px',
      color: 'red'
    }, {
      x: '220',
      y: '230',
      r: '4px',
      color: 'red'
    }, {
      x: '320',
      y: '250',
      r: '4px',
      color: 'red'
    }, {
      x: '380',
      y: '270',
      r: '4px',
      color: 'red'
    }, {
      x: '450',
      y: '290',
      r: '4px',
      color: 'red'
    }],
    [{
      x: '220',
      y: '310',
      r: '4px',
      color: 'blue'
    }, {
      x: '320',
      y: '330',
      r: '4px',
      color: 'blue'
    }, {
      x: '420',
      y: '350',
      r: '4px',
      color: 'blue'
    }, {
      x: '520',
      y: '370',
      r: '4px',
      color: 'blue'
    }, {
      x: '620',
      y: '410',
      r: '4px',
      color: 'blue'
    }],
    [{
      x: '305',
      y: '370',
      r: '4px',
      color: 'green'
    }, {
      x: '370',
      y: '420',
      r: '4px',
      color: 'green'
    }, {
      x: '440',
      y: '410',
      r: '4px',
      color: 'green'
    }, {
      x: '490',
      y: '400',
      r: '4px',
      color: 'green'
    }, {
      x: '600',
      y: '490',
      r: '4px',
      color: 'green'
    }],

  ]);

  const svgRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {

    if (svgRef.current) {

      const svg = select(svgRef.current);

      // X-AXIS
      const xScale = scaleLinear()
        .domain([xAxisData.min, xAxisData.max])
        .range([0, meta.xWidth]);

      const xAxis = axisBottom(xScale);

      svg
        .select(".x-axis")
        .style("transform", `translateY(${meta.yWidth}px)`)
        .call(xAxis);

      // Y-AXIS
      const yScale = scaleLinear()
        .domain([yAxisData.min, yAxisData.max])
        .range([meta.yWidth, 0]);

      const yAxis = axisLeft(yScale);

      svg
        .select(".y-axis")
        .call(yAxis);

      // DOT PLOT
      plots.map(points => {
        svg
          .selectAll("circle")
          .data(points)
          .join("circle")
          .attr("cx", value => xScale(value.x))
          .attr("cy", value => yScale(value.y))
          .attr("r", value => value.r)
          .attr("fill", value => value.color)
          .attr("stroke", value => value.color);
      });
    }
  }, [xAxisData, yAxisData, meta, plots]);

  return ( <
    svg viewBox = {
      `0 0 ${meta.xWidth} ${meta.yWidth}`
    }
    ref = {
      svgRef
    } >
    <
    g className = "x-axis" / >
    <
    g className = "y-axis" / >
    <
    /svg>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(< DotsPlot />, document.querySelector("body"));
```

```css
svg {
  width: 80%;
  height: auto;
  background: #eee;
  overflow: visible;
  margin: 5%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/6.2.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following. You kept selecting the same circles and updating them. I use a group per entry in `plots` and add circles for each group. This way, the other circles don't get deleted.

Another workaround would be to flatten `plots` using `Array.prototype.flat()`, and then just remove the `plots.map(` part.

```js
const useState = React.useState;
const useRef = React.useRef;
const useEffect = React.useEffect;
const select = d3.select;
const scaleLinear = d3.scaleLinear;
const axisBottom = d3.axisBottom;
const axisLeft = d3.axisLeft;

const DotsPlot = () => {

  const [xAxisData] = useState({
    min: 100,
    max: 700
  });

  const [yAxisData] = useState({
    min: 200,
    max: 500
  });

  const [meta] = useState({
    xWidth: 600,
    yWidth: 300,
  });

  const [plots] = useState([
    [{
      x: '120',
      y: '210',
      r: '4px',
      color: 'red'
    }, {
      x: '220',
      y: '230',
      r: '4px',
      color: 'red'
    }, {
      x: '320',
      y: '250',
      r: '4px',
      color: 'red'
    }, {
      x: '380',
      y: '270',
      r: '4px',
      color: 'red'
    }, {
      x: '450',
      y: '290',
      r: '4px',
      color: 'red'
    }],
    [{
      x: '220',
      y: '310',
      r: '4px',
      color: 'blue'
    }, {
      x: '320',
      y: '330',
      r: '4px',
      color: 'blue'
    }, {
      x: '420',
      y: '350',
      r: '4px',
      color: 'blue'
    }, {
      x: '520',
      y: '370',
      r: '4px',
      color: 'blue'
    }, {
      x: '620',
      y: '410',
      r: '4px',
      color: 'blue'
    }],
    [{
      x: '305',
      y: '370',
      r: '4px',
      color: 'green'
    }, {
      x: '370',
      y: '420',
      r: '4px',
      color: 'green'
    }, {
      x: '440',
      y: '410',
      r: '4px',
      color: 'green'
    }, {
      x: '490',
      y: '400',
      r: '4px',
      color: 'green'
    }, {
      x: '600',
      y: '490',
      r: '4px',
      color: 'green'
    }],

  ]);

  const svgRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {

    if (svgRef.current) {

      const svg = select(svgRef.current);

      // X-AXIS
      const xScale = scaleLinear()
        .domain([xAxisData.min, xAxisData.max])
        .range([0, meta.xWidth]);

      const xAxis = axisBottom(xScale);

      svg
        .select(".x-axis")
        .style("transform", `translateY(${meta.yWidth}px)`)
        .call(xAxis);

      // Y-AXIS
      const yScale = scaleLinear()
        .domain([yAxisData.min, yAxisData.max])
        .range([meta.yWidth, 0]);

      const yAxis = axisLeft(yScale);

      svg
        .select(".y-axis")
        .call(yAxis);

      // DOT PLOT
      svg
        .selectAll("g.plots")
        .data(plots)
        .join("g")
        .selectAll("circle")
        .data(d => d)
        .join("circle")
        .attr("cx", value => xScale(value.x))
        .attr("cy", value => yScale(value.y))
        .attr("r", value => value.r)
        .attr("fill", value => value.color)
        .attr("stroke", value => value.color);
    }
  }, [xAxisData, yAxisData, meta, plots]);

  return ( <
    svg viewBox = {
      `0 0 ${meta.xWidth} ${meta.yWidth}`
    }
    ref = {
      svgRef
    } >
    <
    g className = "x-axis" / >
    <
    g className = "y-axis" / >
    <
    /svg>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(< DotsPlot />, document.querySelector("body"));
```

```css
svg {
  width: 80%;
  height: auto;
  background: #eee;
  overflow: visible;
  margin: 5%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/6.2.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You copied my code, but you haven't implemented your solution.

Comment: Apologies, something must have gone wrong. Fixed now

Comment: "g.plots":  should i create <g> elements with class '.plots' into jsx code?

Comment: No that will happen automatically

Comment: I think there is an error in your code. I implemented it in my project, but it works only if I don't pass dataset to circle instead of g.

Comment: Which dataset? `plots`?

Comment: ```svg.selectAll("g.plots").join("g").selectAll("circle").data(plots)```  In my code I didn't use dynamic <g>, but preexisting ones. With your code d3.js created the <g> elements for each circle, but I had to create one for each single plot. Your solution is always correct, but in my code I had to modify it a bit.